# Plesk 12.5 + Wordpress installation in subfolder

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I've looked a lot before posting, but none of the solutions I've read of seems to solve my issue.

I'm running Plesk 12.5.30 over Debian. 
Apache + nginx running on the server.

I manage a wordpress site in my domain (let's call it example.com) and the site runs just fine. 
For testing purposes I need to make a second (completely separate - not multisite) installation of a wordpress site that is located in example.com/test and I need both sites to be working at the same time. 
The installation located in example.com/test comes from a backup from a different site. I already corrected all the values in the WP database.

The problem is: I can't access the installation located in example.com/test - I always get "too many redirects" error. Strange thing: if I try to login at the address example.com/test/wp-login.php I get the Wordpress login page, but even if I enter the correct login info, I always get just the login page.

I tried all the possible (that I know of) configurations of .htaccess, but I think the problem stands in the Apache-Nginx domain configuration.

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe issue related url rewrite or .htaccess

Comment: For sure, that's my opinion too, but I can't find the proper combination of url rewrite rules and .htaccess
I also wonder if I need to word on the parent (root) .htaccess or on the subdirectory .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in PLesk forum (https://talk.plesk.com/threads/wordpress-installation-in-sub-folder.341468/)

> You cannot do it, because rewrite configurations of the site in /a
>   influence the site in /a/b. Instead, create a subdomain as a separate
>   webspace directory and do the second installation into that subdomain.

I solved by creating the sub-domain and configured properly DNS settings.

Just for curiosity: does anyone know if this happens because of nginx (I never worked with nginx before)? 
I performed the solution above with other services in the past and it worked just fine.